# Start the web application as soon as IIS is started

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, scheduled-tasks, iis-8.5

I have a scheduler service written in MVC web application. I set the `AutoStart` to `TRUE` and `StartMode` to `AlwaysRunning` in IIS. 
I am expecting that when IIS started the code written in Global.asax `Application_Start()` event should get executed automatically. But it is not happening, it is executing only when I hit the URL of that virtual directory in browser.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Application_Start only fires when the application is first initializated, which only occurs on first call to the URL, not on AppPool start.

There are some modules for IIS7.5+ to allow auto initialization, you can find more details here: [Run Application_Start immediately when application pool restarts in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623303/run-application-start-immediately-when-application-pool-restarts-in-iis)

Comment: Thank you, I followed the steps as mentioned in the above link, but  Application_Start() is not called when AppPool is started.

Comment: What IIS version are you using?

Comment: My Dev environment is IIS 7.5 and Production environment is IIS 8.5